# Screen Locker app which changes the android firmware

Tags: android, screen, firmware

I know that there are many screen locker applications that can replace the current android lock-screen. I want to develop my own screen locker application and I want to find out if there are any tutorials on how to write a software that changes the functionality of the android firmware such as the current lock-screen. I have searched through the internet but I haven't managed to find any good tutorials.

Thanks for your time. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a lot of useful information into the presentation of marakana group. [Here](http://marakana.com/forums/android/general/269.html) is a link to the lecture that consists of two parts. In these lectures basics around android platform development are explained.